# DELETE FILE WITH FOLDER XP_CMDSHELL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to delete file with folder using sql
so i am using xp_cmdshell.

My Folder structure is

```
                       Folder-1
                              |
                              |
Folder 2 ----------------------------------------------Folder -3
|                                                         |
files.csv                                               files.csv
```

I need to delete Folder-1, so that it will delete Folder 2 and folder 3 and the files containing it.

I tried using   set @cmd= 'RMDIR  "C:\Folder-1'

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

**RMDIR needs the folder to be empty**. so we need to first delete the file using del command.
Then using RMDIR to delete folder 2 and folder 3, then using RMDIR to delete folder-1

Is there anyway to delete the folder with file using single command by xp_cmdshell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try RMDIR /S /Q C:\Folder-1

The /S Removes all files and directories in the specified directory/folder. the /Q is quiet mode and will not ask if its ok to delete.

HTH